# PHPMailer sends duplicate email to the same recipient but with different random generated code for email verification

Tags: php, android, phpmailer

Everytime I clicked a button from android it sends mail to the receiver twice. So this email sending is when I request for a resend verification code for email registration. When I click to resend the verification button, I receive the email with a random generated string ($code) then seconds later I receive the same email but difference random generated string ($code).

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST')
{
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $actionType = $_POST['actionType'];
    $count = 0;

    $random_string = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 6)), 0, 6);
    $verification_code = $random_string;

    $verificationQuery = "SELECT * FROM email_verification WHERE email='$Email'";
    $verificationResults = mysqli_query($conn, $verificationQuery);

$result = array();
if($actionType == 'Resend')
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($verificationResults)===1)
    {
        $updateCode = "UPDATE email_verification SET verification_code = '$verification_code' WHERE email='$Email'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $updateCode))
        {
            $result["success"]="1";
            $result["message"]="Verification Code Sent";


            echo json_encode($result);
            sendingEmail($Email, $verification_code, $count);

        }
        else
        {
            $result["success"]="0";
            $result["message"]="Verification Code Not Sent";

            echo json_encode($result);

        }
    }
       }
    else
      {
           $result["success"]="0";
           $result["message"]="Verification Code Not Sent";

           echo json_encode($result);
       }

       mysqli_close($conn);

    }
    function sendingEmail($emailSent, $code)
    {
      $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
      //Server settings
      $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
      $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
      $mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.hostinger.ph';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username = 'developers.itproj2@itproj2captcha.xyz';                 // SMTP username
      $mail->Password = '*************';                           // SMTP password
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
      $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

      //Recipients
      $mail->setFrom('developers.itproj2@itproj2captcha.xyz', 'Developer @ITPROJ2');
      $mail->addAddress($emailSent, '');     // Add a recipient

      $mail->addReplyTo('developers.itproj2@itproj2captcha.xyz', 'Email Verification');

      //Content
      $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
      $mail->Subject = 'Email Verification';
      $mail->Body    = 'Hi, <br><br>This is your verification code for your 
      email <b>'.$code.'</b><br><br>Thanks,<br>Group CAPTCHA ';

      $status = $mail->Send();
      $count++;
      echo "No. of times script was used: " . $count;
      if ($status) 
      {  
          echo 'Message has been sent.';  
      } 
      else 
      {  
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;   
      }
    }
?>
```

EDITED:

Here is my full resendCode.php codes. I've included a way to check if the script was ran twice with $count++, but the log from android

No. of times script was used: 1

Below is the android snippet code. CodeVerification.java. I've also tried checking if the method codeReset(); was called twice by incrementing count. the log shows

08-03 22:32:09.195 6702-7690/com.example.joshua.itproj2 D/count: count: 1

08-03 22:32:11.760 6702-7690/com.example.joshua.itproj2 D/count: count: 1

```
public void codeReset(final String email, final String type)
{
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL2,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                        if(success.equals("1"))
                        {
                            AlertDialogBox("Success", message);
                            cVerifyProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialogBox("Failed", message);
                            cVerifyProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        prompt = success;

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        AlertDialogBox("Error", e.toString());
                        cVerifyProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    final String result=response.toString();
                    Log.d("response", "result : "+result);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    AlertDialogBox("Error", error.toString());
                    cVerifyProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Email",email);
            params.put("actionType",type);

            int count = 0;
            count++;
            Log.d("count", "count: "+ count);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: _"but different random generated string"_ - like a "xyz23098fdlkmsdfpo"?? Or is just the `$code` random?

Comment: to me it sounds more like a problem of the php code that calls `sendingEmail()` _or_ the android code that calls the php script - which we don't see.

Comment: Your function is being called more than once; figure out why. It's not a problem in the function itself.

Comment: I have included the full codes of ResendCode.php and an android snippet code for codeReset()